# Ruby TypeError: no implicit conversion of fixnum into string using json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am getting error during api testing using post(url, json). 
I have already used .to_i, and whatever I got suggestions from stack overflow. But still not working. I am using ubantu 14.04 LTS. Rails 5.0, 
my code is like that:

```
post "/api/...",
params: { email: "email@mailinator.com", password: "xyz", ttl: 300 }
assert_response :success
```

problem is with field `ttl:`.
if I remove this field then everything is working fine.
but I have to add `"ttl"` and it having numeric value like `"1234"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, this issue solved by using .to_json .
json was considering values as a string instead of taking actual type of data.
I used, following format.

- params: { email: "email@mailinator.com", password: "xyz", ttl: 300}.to_json

now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value as a string...

```
post "/api/...",
params: { email: "email@mailinator.com", password: "xyz", ttl: '300' }
assert_response :success
```

In your post method if you need `ttl` to be an integer then over there you can do...

```
params[:ttl].to_i
```